# Writing a java program containing two classes

Tags: java, class, methods

I've attempted to write a Java program containing two classes: Dog and a driver class Kennel.

A dog consists of the following information:

- An integer age.
- A string name. If the given name contains non-alphabetic characters, initialize to Wolfy.
- A string bark representing the vocalization the dog makes when they ‘speak’.
- A boolean representing hair length; true indicates short hair.
- A float weight representing the dog’s weight (in pounds).
- An enumeration representing the type of tail (LONG, SHORT, NONE).

A dog has the following methods:

- A default constructor.
- A constructor that takes a name as argument.
- A method private boolean validName(String) that returns true / false whether the given name contains non-alphabetic characters.
- humanAge that computes and returns the age of the dog in “human years.”
- speak that returns the dog’s bark...

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to do the method for validName. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Also do I do the method for speak the same way or no? The code is attached below.

```
package lab101;


public class Dog 
{
    public enum TailType 
    {
        LONG, SHORT, NONE
    }    

    private int age;
    private float weight;
    private String name;
    private String bark;
    private boolean hairLength;
    private TailType tail;

    //Default Constructor--> initializes an object (called once)every constructor 
    //must initialize all the classes attributes!!
    public Dog()
    {
        age = 0;
        weight = 0;
        name = "";
        bark = "";
        hairLength = false; 
        tail = TailType.NONE;   
    }

    //Overloaded constructor (must have an argument)
    public Dog(String theName)
    {
        age = 0;
        weight = 0;
        name = theName;
        bark = "";
        hairLength = false; 
        tail = TailType.NONE;   
    }

    //If the name contains non-alphabetic characters
    private boolean validName(String str)
    {
        str = str.toLowerCase();

        if (str.length() <= 0)
        {

        }  


        return false; 
    }


    //Computes the dog's age in human years.
    public int humanAge()
    {
        int theAge = 7 * age;

        return theAge;
    }

    //Returns the value of bark if true
    public String(speak)
    {
        return bark;
    }


    //Method: <privacy: (private, public)> <return-type (data type or void)> <methodName>(<argument>){
    //        <body>
    //        return
    // }

    public String toString()
    {
        String str = "";
        str += "Name: " + name;
        str += "Weight: " + weight;
        str += "Bark: " + bark;
        str += "Hair Length: " + hairLength;
        str += "Tail: " + tail;
        str += "Age: " + age;

        return str;
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly validName method do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am having trouble trying to figure out how to do the method for validName.

Assuming your validName method checks whether a valid name was given by checking whether there exist only alphabets:

```
//Return true if name is valid
private boolean validName(String str)
{
    if(str == null || str.length() == 0)
        return false;
    return str.toLowerCase().matches("[a-z]+"); //Name only has a-z(A-Z)
}
```

> Also do I do the method for speak the same way or no?

Well, I do not know what do you mean by "the same way". But your speak method is incorrect.

According to your description, it should be:

```
public String speak(){
    return bark;
}
```

---

**Something you did not ask, but could be done better:**

You are implementing your class constructor twice. You could have invoke the constructor like this:

```
public Dog(){
    this("");  //invoke Dog(String)
}

public Dog(String theName){
    age = 0;
    weight = 0;
    name = theName;
    bark = "";
    hairLength = false; 
    tail = TailType.NONE;   
}
```

The effect of the above is the same as what you did, but this is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this if you don't know regular expression:

```
private boolean validName(String str)
{   char[] letters = str.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < letters.length; i++){
        int oneLetter = (int) letters[i];
        if( !(oneLetter > 64 && oneLetter < 91)) // letters as ASCII for A-Z
            return false; // if anyone is not A-Z then return false

    }
    return  true; // if every letter is valid then return true
}
```